# Browser refresh doesn't work in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have created my first react-js app, just saying 'Hello world'. After I change the 'Hello world' to another text, nothing changes when I refresh the browser, even if I empty the cache. The changes take place only when I close the local server and reopen it with `npm start`. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see whats going on?  include your html and your component that has 'hello world'/changed text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create new react app from-scratch. You can use :

```
> npx create-react-app my-app
> cd my-app
> npm start
```

After that, you will have the initial configured react project structure :

```
my-app
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── .gitignore
├── public
│   └── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
└── src
    └── App.css
    └── App.js
    └── App.test.js
    └── index.css
    └── index.js
    └── logo.svg
    └── registerServiceWorker.js
```

See react app seed in Github : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app.

Comment: Would it be different if I follow this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm ? Would this be the reason that I cannot refresh the browser ?

Comment: Yes, with `npx` you don't need to a configure the webpack. You have a registerServiceWorker.js instead and your app is run with "start": "react-scripts start". In your tuto, it's start your app with "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot" in package.json

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337918/difference-between-webpack-babel-and-react-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Sam's answer is probably the best way to do it but if you want do refresh it without adding all the bells and whistles of create-react-app you can go for browsersync.

https://browsersync.io/

It watches over your CSS, HTML, JS.  I usually use create-react-app but in some cases browsersync does the trick as well.